# Would the "Cavendish drawl" be considered a dialect?

Tags: british-english, dialects

I was reading the biography *[Georgiana](http://www.amanda-foreman.com/uk-book.shtml)*,  by Amanda Foreman, and came across a description of what she calls the *Cavendish drawl*, an accent of sorts that was spoken by the Cavendish family. One [blog](http://www.yek.me.uk/archive13.html#blog126) refers to it as a *patois* and wrote that:

> the Foreman biography quotes various examples of the phenomenon called variously ‘Cavendish drawl’ and ‘Devonshire drawl’ both of which terms, even taking into account her mention of “bal-*cony*, con-*tem*-plate” and “*cow*-cumber”, are no doubt less appropriate than the third one ‘Cavendish patois’.

He goes on,

> In the OED Murray remarked in 1885 “Till c1825 the pronunc. was regularly bælˈkəʊnɪ; but ˈbælkənɪ..., ‘which,’ said Samuel Rogers, ‘makes me sick,’ is now established.” ...
>   OED dodgily gives the con`template stressing in second place (as an allegedly current usage) even tho retaining Murray’s century-plus-old comment that it “begins to have a flavour of age”.
>
> On cowcumber it gives his 1893 remark that such a pronunciation was “still that recognized by Walker; but Smart 1836 says ‘no well-taught person, except of the old school, now says cow-cumber ... although any other pronunciation ... would have been pedantic some thirty years ago”. **Other items of the patois Foreman quotes are yellow, gold and spoil presumably pronounced as /jӕlə, guːld/ and /spaɪl/ and a “baby-talk” style you pronounced with its yod dropped.**... Except for this last item, these were all probably merely old-fashioned. For example Wyld's *History of Modern Colloquial English* (1920/36 p. 239) sed of goold that “It was a very usual though by no means the only pronunciation in the seventeenth and eighteenth centuries among good speakers.”

Whether or not this way of speaking was old-fashioned, it was (according to Foreman) used in the Cavendish household, and was at least partially adopted by people of that social circle. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialect) says that a dialect is:

> a variety of a language that is a characteristic of a particular group of the language's speakers.[1] The term is applied most often to regional speech patterns, but a dialect may also be defined by other factors, such as social class.

A patois, again per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patois), is:

> any language that is considered nonstandard, although the term is not formally defined in linguistics. It can refer to pidgins, creoles, dialects, and other forms of native or local speech

So how would the "Cavendish drawl" be linguistically categorized? Is it a dialect? A cant? Something else?

Comment: I do not know the exact answer... But wouldn't it be considered a dialect if it is spoken locally? If it is only spoken by a family and its social circle, I don't think it would be considered as dialect.

Comment: Voting to close on the grounds there can't possibly be a single answer as to how many speakers are needed to promote highly localised "idiomatic usage" to recognised "dialect".

Comment: ...though I will just say google only gives 15 hits for "cavendish drawl". And one of those, obviously, is for this very page. So this one definitely *doesn't* qualify as a recognised dialect.

Comment: @FumbleFingers -- You object to one part of my question, but not the crux of it. I am looking for someone with knowledge not received by a mere Google search (which I did) to explain whether this might be a dialect

Comment: According to wiki a dialect is a type of patois, ([patois](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patois)) and patois is not a formal linguistic term. Maybe the distinction should be between a dialect and a [cant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cant_%28language%29)

Comment: @simchona: I object to the specific question about "Cavendish drawl" as being "too localised". But I also object to the broader question of where to draw the line between various different terms used to describe localised language variants, as being basically "not constructive". Be honest, what do you seriously expect to learn from any answers you might get?

Comment: @FumbleFingers: This question can be applied to whenever a small group of people speak a certain way. Yes, I expect to learn something. I didn't know the Sociolinguistic term that ChaosGamer brought up.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Why isn't figuring out the differences between terms used to describe language variants constructive?

Comment: @simchona: Yes indeed. But most relevant terms don't have absolute definitions, and there's considerable overlap. If you'd asked about one specific difference (between *pidgin* and *creole*, for example), that would be fair game, because it *can* be answered. Asking how many speakers you need sharing a language variant before you call it a *dialect* is simply an invitation to open-ended discussion.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I took out the "how many" question. In its current form, I believe the question can be answered.

Comment: @simchona: Fair enough. I can't undo my vote to close, but I think ChaosGamer has nailed the remaining question by pointing out that technically speaking every single person's version of language can be considered a "minimal dialect". I don't think *cant* is relevant, as it's just an archaic term for "specialised terminology" (used by criminals, businessmen, etc.) So far as I know *patois* is just "localised dialect", but it's usually applied to isolated rustic communities. Really, there's only "dialect" here, and at a pinch it can go all the way down to a single speaker.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: If you write that as an answer (since you seem to know a lot about this), I'd be happy to see it.

Comment: @simchona let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1040/discussion-between-fumblefingers-and-simchona)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What about a *minimal dialect*:

> A dialect spoken by one individual is called an idiolect.
>   Everyone has small differences between the way they
>   talk and the way even their family and best friends
>   talk, creating a *minimal dialect*.

*Source*: [Sociolinguistics lecture slides](http://www.ling.ohio-state.edu/~kdk/201/spring02/slides/variation-4up.pdf)

Comment: I'll accept because of "minimal dialect" and how @fumblefingers explained it in a comment.

Comment: +1 I like the idea that this "Cavendish drawl" is nothing more than a slightly extended idiolect!

Answer (score 2):

Slang, jargon, and cant are terms used to refer to words used by small groups or sections of population. The Devonshire drawl was more like Valleygirl speak  than a dialect. They were a group with their own jargon  used to keep outsiders out.